# Subtracting predefined time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I am having table time in mysql database with one attribute of type "TIME" which contains default value "09:00:00". what I am trying to do is to get this value and subtract it from current time.

```
include 'connection.php';
$time = mysql_query("SELECT start_time FROM time");
$s = mysql_fetch_assoc($time);
$start_time = strtotime($s['start_time']);
$time_now = date("H:i:s");
$delay = ($time_now - $start_time);
```

However it never worked the way I need. result always like 00:00:00 
what i want to achieve is something like:

```
$start_time = 09:00:00
$time_now = 09:34:23
so $delay should be 00:34:23.
```

any help to achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you do it in MySQL using date arithmetic functions.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: converting a date is not math, it's an algorithm. You can't just subtract dates, you need to use a library that knows what you are trying to do. PHP `DateTime::Sub` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: MySQL `SUBTIME` is probably best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small bug in your code....  look below

```
include 'connection.php';
$time = mysql_query("SELECT start_time FROM time");
$s = mysql_fetch_assoc($time);

$start_time = strtotime($s['start_time']);
$time_now = date("H:i:s");
$delay = ($time_now - $start_time); //BUG! String minus timestamp here...
```

Fix that second block with:

```
$start_time = strtotime($s['start_time']);
$delay =  date( "H:i:s", time() - $start_time );
```

Agree with others though, this is really cleanly done on the database side as well.

Hope this helps